# Getting a list of all the Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic folders

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Windows will allow you to have more than one music folder. How do I query the path for all the folders. I know that the following will get the current set folder but I want the others.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic)
```

On my system this will produce the following folder. `D:\Users\Bobby\Music`. However that is not enough. I have another folder that is a music folder located at `C:\Users\Bobby\SkyDrive\Music`.

Basically I want to iterate all the folders in the MyMusic library from my Windows Store application.

[image]

Comment: This is not a duplicate because I'm trying to access it via a Windows Store application using the WinRT API. Update question to state that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is how you access all MP3 music is a Windows Music library.

```
var options = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByMusicProperties, new List<string> { ".mp3" });
options.SetThumbnailPrefetch(ThumbnailMode.MusicView, 256, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);

var query = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);
var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    /* Access MP3s */
}
```