# Get all directories within an Explorer Library

Tags: c#

How can I get all the library locations added to My Music?

For this example, I have added these directories to the library:

```
E:\My Music
E:\Mp3
```

I tried:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
```

But it returns:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\Music
```

[image]

Comment: Can you just add the directory one by one manually if only two folders exist?

Comment: i have lots of directory to add on my library location so adding it one by one is not an option for me.. :)

Comment: You got your work cut out for you, but here is a great example on how it's done. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143038/Parsing-Windows-7-Libraries-Without-NET-4-or-the-W

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud thanks for the response, i'll review it.

Comment: I don't suppose it's sufficient to discover the path to the Music Library folder itself? You can do that using the [`SHGetKnownFolderPath` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) and passing the value `FOLDERID_MusicLibrary`. Much easier than enumerating all of the folders *added* to the library, and should be sufficient for most uses.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Based on your link, it suggests that this is much easier to do with .NET 4

Answer (score 1):

Any libraries added to Media Player should end up in the `AppData` directory.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Music.library-ms"
```

Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to develop a Windows Store Application? If yes, try with the Windows.Store library as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098527/getting-a-list-of-all-the-environment-specialfolder-mymusic-folders)

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.musiclibrary

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar and [posted a full solution with code using Windows API Code Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31241361/277601) at this other StackOverflow question. In your case, you would find the code that says:

```
        ICollection<IKnownFolder> allSpecialFolders = Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.KnownFolders.All;
```

And then iterate over these folders to find the one that matches your need:

```
    string fpath = "";
    // Iterate over each folder and find the one we want
    foreach ( var folder in allSpecialFolders )
    {
        if ( folder.ParsingName == foldername )
        {
            // We now have access to the xml path
            fpath = folder.Path;
        }
    }

    if ( fpath == "" )
        return null;

    var intFolders = GetLibraryInternalFolders(fpath);

    return intFolders.Folders.ToList();
```

And then use the `GetLibraryInternalFolders()` function to return the multiple folders inside that. Anyway, check out my full-code solution at the other question.